# How does Rust store enum values in arrays?

Tags: memory, enums, rust

The following is valid Rust:

```
enum Foo {
    One(i32, i32, i32),
    Two { x: i32, y: i32 },
}

fn main() {
    let x: [Foo; 2] = [Foo::One(1, 2, 3), Foo::Two { x: 1, y: 2 }];
}
```

How does Rust store this? The first element is 12 bytes while the second one is 8 (plus a tag byte in the beginning I guess). Does it only store references to the elements in the array?

Comment: The same way it stores enum values anywhere else, FWIW.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All variants of an enum use the same amount of memory (in case of your `Foo` type, 16 bytes, at least on my machine). The size of the enum's values is determined by its largest variant (`One`, in your example).

Therefore, the values can be stored in the array directly.

Answer (score 11):

Rust being a systems programming language, you can just ask it!

```
use std::mem;

enum Foo {
    One(i32, i32, i32),
    Two { x: i32, y: i32 },
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", mem::size_of::<Foo>());
}
```

This [prints 16](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=134907b78de71cad77aa5c3e196fdb7d&version=stable&backtrace=0) on the playground.

And note that I did not specify whether I talked about `One` or `Two`, because it does not matter. `Foo` has a unique size.

---

As a rule of thumb, you might want to avoid storing a very large variant. One solution, if a single variant is much bigger than the other, is to reach out to `Box`.