# How is memory allocation for vectors efficient when storing multiple types using enums?

Tags: vector, memory-management, rust, heap-memory

The Rust documentation says:

> Vectors can only store values that are the same type.

This makes sense because every time you want to push a new value in the vector, it needs to know how much memory to allocate for the new value.

If we have:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And then we want to add another value:

```
v.push(12);
```

It will allocate 32 bits for this new value. This makes perfect sense.

Let's say we have this code which store multiple types using enums:

```
enum EnumTypes {
    Float(f64),
    Bool(bool),
}

let mut v: Vec<EnumTypes> = Vec::new();
```

This is valid code; it follows Rust's rules regarding values in the vector being the same type, `EnumTypes` in this case, then we push a `EnumTypes::Bool` value to the vector:

```
v.push(EnumTypes::Bool(true));
```

How does Rust knows how much memory to allocate for `EnumTypes::Bool(true)` when we push it in the vector? Does Rust allocate sufficient memory to hold the largest type in the enum (f64 in this case)? If this is the case isn't kind of inefficient to allocate so much memory just to hold a bool type? Of course this flexibility is super nice compared to other languages but coming from a C/C++ background I feel like so much memory is wasted using this feature of the language.

Comment: *the largest type in the enum* — yes (duplicate [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40365336/155423)). *kind of inefficient to allocate so much memory* — maybe (duplicate [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27324821/155423) and [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51200405/155423)).

Comment: *coming from a C/C++ background* — how would you propose solving the problem of creating a vector of heterogenous types in either of these languages in a manner that is safe and "efficient"?

Comment: i'n not proposing anything and i'm definitely not saying that this flexibility is not nice, but if you have some hard memory allocation requirements, you should keep this is mind when writing such code. since i am new to Rust i just want to understand how allocation works. @Shepmaster

Comment: For something to be **in**efficient, there needs to be some technique that is more efficient.

Comment: C have the same limitation.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that most allocations happening here are very cheap (save for the vector allocation and re-allocations to increase capacity), so pushing new values (such as that `i32` or  `EnumTypes`) is not something as expensive as a `make_unique` in C++. Regarding efficiency, saving the space "lost" as a consequence of storing inline `Sized` values deriving from a sum of types of different sizes requires a much more complex vector data structure.